# Let $ X = $ R and let $ \mathfrak T $ $= \{U \subseteq X : 2 \notin U \; or \; U = \emptyset\} $ Closed sets?

Tags: general-topology

Let $ X = $ **R**  and let $ \mathfrak T $ $= \{U \subseteq X : 2 \notin U \; or \; U = \emptyset\} $

I first have to describe the closed sets of X.
I think these are $ \emptyset $ and every set not including 2. Is this correct?

I need to then find the closure of $\{3\}$
I do note that this is an example of of the excluded point topology but I am not sure how to use that or if I need to.

Comment: If I am correct about the closed sets of T then how to I show/write all the sets not including 2.

Comment: Is $\mathfrak{T}$ a topology? A topology has to contain the whole set $X$, but clearly $X\notin\mathfrak{T}$. Or you mean the topology generated by $\mathfrak{T}$?

Comment: I am going to say that $ \mathfrak T $ is generating a topology...

Comment: OK. That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the topology generated by $\mathfrak{T}$. First we note that every singleton set except $\{2\}$ is an element of $\mathfrak{T}$, hence an element of $\mathcal{T}$. Since a topology is closed under taking unions, it follows that every set not containing $2$ is an element of $\mathcal{T}$. On the other hand, if $U\in\mathcal{T}$, then one can easily see that either $2\notin U$ or $U\in\{\emptyset,X\} $. Hence $\mathcal{T}$ contains precisely $\emptyset, X$ and those sets not containing $2$. Hence the closed sets are $\emptyset, X$ and those containing $2$.

To find the closure of $\{3\}$, recall that the closure of a set is the smallest closed set containing this set. With the identification of closed sets above, we immediately conclude that the closure of $\{3\}$ is $\{2,3\}$.